# sed or awk to append to specific line

Tags: bash, google-chrome, awk, sed

There is a file that I'd like to edit from a bash script

```bsh
if [[ -n "$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" ]]; then
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  \
    --user-data-dir="$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" "$@"
else
  exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"
fi
```

I would like to append to the end of any line containing *exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@"*  the string

```bsh
  --user-data-dir
```

The result would over write the existing file with

```js
    if [[ -n "$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" ]]; then
      exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  \
        --user-data-dir="$CHROME_USER_DATA_DIR" "$@"
    else
      exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome"  "$@" --user-data-dir
    fi
```

I am having difficulty understanding sed and awk, but want to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to use a regexp instead of a string comparison since your white space can apparently vary so that introduces some escaping complexity. Using GNU awk for `-i inplace` and `\s` shorthand for `[[:space:]]`:

```
awk -i inplace '/exec\s+-a\s+"\$0"\s+"\$HERE\/chrome"\s+"\$@"/{$0=$0 " --user-data-dir"} 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to edit your file with GNU sed:

```
sed -i '5s/$/& --user-data-dir/' file
```

Comment: The `&` is not really necessary when you're matching an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, would that append to a set line number? I edited my post to be a little more clear.  The line number can vary a bit.  I'd like to find the line:    "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"   and replace it with the line: "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"  --user-data-dir

Comment: @Tartrantism If you want to match by regex instead of line number, use `/regex/` instead of `5`. In this case, `sed '/"\$0" "\$HERE\/chrome" "\$@"/ s/$/ --user-data-dir/'` should work (untested).

Answer (score 0):

With awk you could do:

```
awk 'NR==5{$0=$0" --user-data-dir"}1' file > newfile
```

Comment: Thanks, would that append to a set line number? I edited my post to be a little more clear.  The line number can vary a bit.  I'd like to find the line:    "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"   and replace it with the line: "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@"  --user-data-dir

Comment: @Tartrantism Then just filter by the regex. Replace `NR==5` with `/myregex/`